# The child process which is made orphan by killing its parent is not getting adopted by init. How do I fix this?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, system

The program is to avoid zombie by forking twice. I am getting the value for parent pid of the orphan process everything but 1, which is not right.

Here is the code that I tried. If there is error in the logic please help me out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t processid;

    if((processid=fork())<0)
        printf("Fork error\n");
    else if(processid==0)
    {
        if((processid=fork())<0)
            printf("Fork error\n");

        if(processid>0)
        {exit(0);}

        sleep(2);
        printf("second child, parent pid =%d\n",getppid());
        exit(0);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
root@kali:~# gedit avoidzombies.c
root@kali:~# gcc avoidzombies.c
root@kali:~# ./a.out
root@kali:~# second child, parent pid =1069
```

Comment: Checked on mac os 10.10 and ubuntu 14.06lts - it does return `1`

Comment: On my system, I also get a different pid -- but that pid corresponds to upstart, which is an init replacement.  So, it's working correctly, but the pid of the init (alternative) process is not 1.

Comment: The way to avoid zombies is to correctly `wait()` for the child to finish in the parent - forking the child just creates a second Z if you don't do that.  I suspect what you are trying to do is let `init()` handle the reaping of the grandchild automatically - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665642/why-do-i-have-to-wait-for-child-processes for details.  (Note your code differs crucially from the example there by that `wait()` call...   also, uh...  don't do that, probably  =) )

Comment: @Dmitri , it seems that the answer given by you is the answer to my problem. I checked it online and it do say that Kali linux(which happens to be my working OS) has adopted Upstart event based alternative init daemon process.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, I also get a different pid -- but that pid corresponds to upstart, which is an init replacement. So, it's working correctly, but the pid of the init (alternative) process is not 1. – Dmitri