# How do I asynchronously wait for child processes after forking them?

Tags: linux, unix, process, rust

I'm writing a server in Rust which forks multiple processes in a loop and runs `execv`. The forked processes exit properly, but I'm seeing `<defunct>` entries in the process table for all child processes.

I want to get exit statuses of those child processes without blocking my main loop. If I fork and do a `wait` the loop will block. Is there a way to handle this in an asynchronous manner?

I'm using the [nix crate](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/nix/) for forking and execv:

```
loop {
    match fork() {
        Ok(ForkResult::Child) => {
            // run execv here
        }
        Ok(ForkResult::Parent { child_pid }) => {
            // delegate task for wait
            // and continue with loop
        }
        Err(_) => {
            // do some error reporting here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Why do I have to `wait()` for child processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8665642/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR: `nix::sys::wait::WaitPidFlag::WNOHANG`

Comment: @Shepmaster You're right the answer does solve my problem. I need to install a `SIGCHLD` handler and do a `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` option. Thanks.

Comment: do you really need the signal handler if you are just going to check some later time?

Comment: I'm trying to reap zombie processes as soon as possible. Because it's possible that my server will spawing a descent amount of processes and I also need to keep a log of which processes exited with which exit status. I think signal handler would be good choice for this. Is there an alternative way to do the same?

Comment: Nah, if you need to be notified immediately, a signal handler makes sense, they are just pains to do safely. I’d probably be lazy and spin up a separate thread and poll for children every time period.

Comment: @Shepmaster You were right. Spawning a separate thread and reaping zombies every time period is much easier and cleaner than implementing signal handlers. I've implemented it and it works great. Thanks for the support.